# How do you save a variable in blender addon?

Tags: python, add-on

Hello I am currently trying to create a blender addon and I want to save the computer directory that user has chosen. How can I save variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  If you only want to save one or two properties, it's often best to save them in the [Addon Preferences](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html) as there is built in support for setting add-ons, and, as in the manual page, plenty of sample code. The sample code on the preferences page even has a filepath as part of the example.

Here's the code from the manual page, modified to show only the filepath:

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "Example Add-on Preferences",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 65, 0),
    "location": "SpaceBar Search -> Add-on Preferences Example",
    "description": "Example Add-on",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Object",
}


import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, AddonPreferences
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty


class ExampleAddonPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    # this must match the add-on name, use '__package__'
    # when defining this in a submodule of a python package.
    bl_idname = __name__

    filepath: StringProperty(
        name="Example File Path",
        subtype='FILE_PATH',
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="This is a preferences view for our add-on")
        layout.prop(self, "filepath")


class OBJECT_OT_addon_prefs_example(Operator):
    """Display example preferences"""
    bl_idname = "object.addon_prefs_example"
    bl_label = "Add-on Preferences Example"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        preferences = context.preferences
        addon_prefs = preferences.addons[__name__].preferences

        info = ("Path: %s, Number: %d, Boolean %r" %
                (addon_prefs.filepath, addon_prefs.number, addon_prefs.boolean))

        self.report({'INFO'}, info)
        print(info)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

As you can see, you simply need to add a class that derives from `AddonPreferences` and give it one member attribute for each property.  Then you add a `draw` routine for the class. It's used by the preferences editor.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Where is the addon located after you run it? I can't find it

Comment: In the `bl_info` field there is a _location_ attribute.  The value of that attribute, "_SpaceBar Search -> Add-on Preferences Example_" is telling you that you have to use the command search function to find it.  Note, though, that search is invoked by the space bar in some versions of blender and by the F3 key in others.

Comment: oh I didn't catch that thanks :)